# Deleting a row based on date - Date values

Tags: date, google-sheets

My query relates to  [this Google Form responses spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgEBuN07eCQX3bqNTtFo7ot3nAsRMI96oDBFX99p3bk/edit?usp=sharing). I'm trying to adapt the script I got from [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85218/how-to-delete-a-row-in-a-google-sheet-based-on-date).

```js
function cleanup() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var InAYear = (Date.now()/86400000 + 25569) + 365;
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0;  i--) {
    if ( values[i][5] >= InAYear) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }  
}
```

I'm trying to get this to compare the date in the Start Date column of the sheet with the date in a year from now and delete the row if the column entry is greater than this (ie. if the date on the sheet is more than a year in advance). However, I obviously don't understand how to get the two different dates in the same format because examining variable values when debugging shows wildly different values.

Comment: what are the 2 buttons? stack overflow feature/ client side code injection into stack overflow form / spam links? (just asking because I never seen those buttons)

Comment: ok fake alarm :D seems just a feature of Stack overflow that is rarely used :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script code:

```
function cleanup() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0;  i--) {
    if ( values[i][4] != '' && dateDiffInDays(values[i][4],today) > 365 ) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }  
};

function dateDiffInDays(d1,d2) {
  var date1 = new Date(d1);
  var date2 = new Date(d2);
  var timeDiff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
  return Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to delete the rows which have dates older than one year... I will change the code so that it deletes the rows which have dates after one year from now. So in the code instead of dateDiffInDays(today,values[i][4])>365 we should have dateDiffInDays(values[i][4],today) > 365

Comment: I have edited my answer, and I also have updated the code in the spreadsheet share by you. Check it now, its working for me.

Comment: I would Kisham, if I could work out how to do it, lol. I do have one more question though. Is there a way of taking account of the varying number of days in each year? I'd managed that in a field on the sheet, but can't work it out in the script.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have it working, and sending me an email.

```js
function cleanup(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var today = new Date();
  var InAYear = new Date();
  InAYear.setFullYear( today.getFullYear()+1 );
  
  var emailaddress = "****";
  var subject = "Annual Leave Request"; 
  var message = "Annual Leave has been requested as follows:" + "\n\n";
  
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0;  i--) {
    if ( values[i][4] > InAYear ) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
      subject = "Annual Leave Request - Rejected";
      message = "The following annual leave request was rejected due to being more than one year in advance:" + "\n\n";
    }
  } 

  
  for(var field in e.namedValues) { 
    message += field + ':' 
         + "\n" + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
  } 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, subject, message);

}
```

Thank you to Kishan, without who's help I would not have been able to get to this stage.